# Firebase CLI change hosting target

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have two Firebase hosting sites in >Firebase >Hosting >Main (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/example/hosting/main)

```
1. **foobar**.web.app (default project from setup process)
2. **example**.web.app (added as an additional web app under the main project and linked for hosting)
```

These are my **.firebaserc** settings:

```
 {
  "targets": {
    "foobar": {
      "hosting": {
        "foobar": [
          "foobarWebApp"
        ]
      }
    },
    "example": {
      "hosting": {
        "foobar": [
          "foobarWebApp"
        ],
        "example": [
          "foobar"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "default": "foobar"
  }
}
```

After running **firebase deploy** from the **Firebase CLI** the files get deployed to ***foobar***.web.app. How to change it to ***example***.web.app?

I tried `firebase deploy --only hosting:example` but that always returns *Error: An unexpected error has occurred.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you set up the hosting target correctly?

In your CLI,

`firebase target:apply type target-name resource-name`

- type — the relevant Firebase resource type. In your case, use `hosting`.
- target-name — a unique identifier for the Hosting site that you're deploying to (can be anything)
- resource-name — the name of the Hosting site as listed in your Firebase project, in your case `foobar` or `example`

After you've set up deploy targets for your Firebase resources, reference the applied target names in your `firebase.json` configuration file.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets

EDIT:

Your `.firebaserc` should look something like this, (although running that command line statement above should change this already for you, and all you need to update is the `package.json`):

```
"projects": {
    "default": "project-name"
},
"targets": {
    "project-name": {
        "hosting": {
            "example": [ // target-name
                "example-website" // resource-name
            ],
            "foobar": [ // target-name
                "foobar-website" // resource-name
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but still getting the error. I added my firebaserc settings to my question. Are they correct? I only want to deploy to the child WebApp called "example" not to the parent called foobar.

Comment: I just edited my answer, assuming that both foobar and example domains are under the same project

Comment: Thank you,   it was the "hosting": {"site": "example", part that caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

made sense to me to break it down into "definitive descriptive variables"

ex .firebaserc file

```
{
  "targets": {
    "firebaseProjectID": {
      "hosting": {
        "targetValueInFirebase.json": [
          "yourFirebaseHostingDomain"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "cli_alias": "firebaseProjectID"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm have same problem and solved it by this**:

- 1.`delete browser cache` ,
  2.`reopen browser` ,
  3.`run deploy again`
  4.`open Hosting URL in new private window`*